# Swift: Difference between var a: Int { calculateValue() } and var b = { calculateValue() }()

Tags: swift, variables, computed-properties

I am trying to understand the difference between

```
var a: Int { calculateValue() }
```

and

```
var b = { calculateValue() }()
```

I'm a little confused, but I think I get the basics, so I just wanted to make sure I have it right: Is it that the first one is a computed property that will run calculateValue() every single time I use a somewhere and use that value, whereas the second one just assigns the value of the closure to b at the time of initialisation?

Thank you

Comment: The first will be executed every time you call this property the second the closure will be executed only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A

`var a: Int { calculateValue() }` is a computed property, equivalent to:

```
var a: Int {
   get { calculateValue() }
}
```

The computed body is called everytime `a` is accessed, which means `calculateValue` is called on every access (which can be good good, if its value changes, but wasteful if it doesn't)

#### B

`{ calculateValue() }` is a closure of type `() -> Int`, whose body calls `calculateValue`. The trailing `()` calls that closure, which makes it an immediately evaluated closure.

The result (as assigned to the stored property `var b`) is just an `Int` (not at `() -> Int`, because the closure was already called)

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this is a good explanation. Is there a name for the second kind of property? Or just assigning the return of a closure to a variable.

Comment: Not really. The right hand side is referred to as an "immediately evaluated closure expression"  (known more commonly from JavaScript as an IIFE, "immediately evaluated function expression"). The fact that you happen to assign that result to a `var` is incidental, it could just as easily have been assigned to a local `let` variable, or be directly passed as an argument to a function or operator

Comment: Thanks again for your help.