# How are you able to create an object within its own class definition?

Tags: swift, class

I've been learning Swift and getting confused on how the below is possible.

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let allNumericUSA: DateFormatter = {
        print("Initializing DateFormatter")
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd//yyyy"
        
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

With extensions I understand I am appending onto the class of DateFormatter. I've been reading some explanations regarding the compile and runtime differences when it comes to the class, but I am still scratching my head and hoping there is a more simplistic explanation I can grasp. How is the DateFormatter being referenced inside itself, and then a second time within the static let? Why? All I keep thinking is that spiderman meme where they are all pointing at each other. Where is the point of origin of information? Also, what is the use case of this? If the point of the extension is to append onto code we can't see, shouldn't it be as simple as:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    allNumericUSA.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63814233/1187415

Comment: Also keep in mind that this has little to do with extensions. A Swift class can easily have references to itself in its own properties and methods. Look at [`UserDefaults.standard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard) for an example. It's also not specific to Swift. Objective-C and many other languages allow for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *static factory method* (though it poses as a property). It belongs to the *class*, not to any instance — it is simply a case of the class making an instance of itself, exactly as it does when you say `init`.

So a good way to understand what's happening here is to realize that `DateFormatter.init()` (aka `DateFormatter()`) and `DateFormatter.allNumericUSA` are the same sort of thing — either way, you talk to DateFormatter *the class*, and you end up with a DateFormatter *instance.*

The ability to add (to a class) ways of generating pre-configured instances of that class is *crucial* to Swift, and Swift itself uses them all the time; just as an example, all named UIColors work this way. In other words, `UIColor.red` and `DateFormatter.allNumericUSA` are *exactly* parallel.

Comment: Please do not write "thank you" comments. The way to thank someone is to upvote and/or accept their answer.

Comment: I do wonder how the compiler manages adding new static stored properties in extensions. You can't add static instance propreties in extensions since it changes the memory map of the object, and extensions can be defined for objects for whom the source code of the original object isn't available. I guess the storage for extension-defined static variables is built into the library/app that contains the extension.

Comment: @DuncanC Swift is open source.